# Category archive page has two URLs even when default theme is active with no active plugins

Tags: categories, permalinks, archives

I've changed my permalinks to Custom: **/%category%/%postname%/**, and that (I suppose) caused my category archive pages to have two URLs. For example, category SPORT is available on **/sport** and **/category/sport**. I would like to keep only one. For some reason, pagination on /sport does not work. How do I fix this?

When I use one of the default permalinks options, it's ok and only /category/sport is available.

I've disabled all the plugins and activated the default theme, and still get this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For example, category SPORT is available on **/sport** and
> **/category/sport**. I would like to keep only one.

I tried to reproduce that issue and I could confirm it's true, at least in WordPress v6.0.1 with the default setup, where WordPress is adding a rewrite rule (which is put at the very bottom in the rewrite rules array/list) with `(.+?)/?$` being the regex (regular expression pattern) and `index.php?category_name=$1` being the query.

And it's probably a core bug, or limitation in the WordPress rewriting system, but for now, you can fix the issue using the [`rewrite_rules_array` filter](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/rewrite_rules_array/) like so:

```php
add_filter( 'rewrite_rules_array', 'wpse_408488' );
function wpse_408488( $rules ) {
    $permalink_structure = get_option( 'permalink_structure' );
    if ( '%category%/%postname%' === trim( $permalink_structure, '/' ) ) {
        unset( $rules['(.+?)/?$'] ); // remove the conflicting rewrite rule
    }

    return $rules;
}
```

So that code will remove the additional rewrite rule (`/sport`), which means the category archive would only be accessible at `/category/<slug>`, e.g. `example.com/category/sport`.

And you can add that to your theme functions file, and remember to flush the rewrite rules — just visit the Permalink Settings admin page without having to do anything.

Comment: This works! Thanks!
I've discovered in the meantime that using Yoast SEO (as I already do) can leave you with only /sport, if you prefer it that way. You can go to Yoast SEO / Search Appearance / Taxonomies / Category URLs (at the bottom) and set Remove the categories prefix? to Remove.

Comment: I'm glad my answer helped, and I don't use Yoast SEO, but thanks for sharing that info :) Cheers!